# Get the lion to run in loops. Tersely

Tags: tex-core, expansion

Various constructions can cause TeX (aka the lion) to go into an infinite loop. The simplest example is `\def~{~}~`, which defines `~` to expand to itself, then expands it. Now, if we exclude macro expansion, getting a loop is more difficult. With pure TeX, the two shortest methods I found (without macros) are

```
\everypar{\the\everypar}.
\toksdef~0~{\the~}\the~.
```

(including the trailing dots); note that the second is not macro expansion, but the expansion of `\the\toks0` in hiding. With eTeX, I got down to

```
\if\unexpanded\fi
```

which has the additional "quality" of being expandable. Here, `\unexpanded` could be replaced by `\detokenize` or `\scantokens`.

1. Why does that trigger an infinite loop?
2. Is there a similarly short TeX constructions which does not use macro expansion (preferably only primitives)?

Comment: perhaps the title should be rather: how to end up with an endless loop or something ...

Comment: @FrankMittelbach do you like this title better? I think it would be nice to have an explanation in your answer of what `\if\unexpanded\fi` does.

Comment: "Wenn ein Löwe sprechen könnte, wit könnten ihn nicht verstehen" -- Ludwig Wittgenstein, *Philosophische Untersuchungen II*, p.190

Comment: Bruno yes like it better, not sure a guy having a runaway lion would recognize ;-) though. Yes sorry, I realized a little too late that I should have answered the first part too. and egreg beat me to it. But then you said you did know it, so why not say it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think to have understood why the infinite loop is triggered. The e-TeX primitive `\unexpanded` is mostly like `\lowercase`: it should be followed by `<general text>`, which in turn is `<filler>{<balanced text><right brace>`. The important bit is `<filler>`, which is an arbitrary sequence of `\relax` commands and spaces (TeXbook, p. 276).

So `\unexpanded` looks for a `{` expanding commands on the go and ignoring `\relax` and space tokens. But it is expandable!

When e-TeX finds `\if\unexpanded\fi`, the primitive `\if` triggers the expansion of `\unexpanded`; but the `\fi` immediately following causes the insertion of a (frozen) `\relax`, because of the unfinished conditional, that `\unexpanded` swallows, leaving an unfinished conditional, which causes the insertion of `\relax`…

Oops, infinite loop. For `\detokenize` and `\scantokens` the situation is the same. In original TeX *no* expandable primitive accepts a `<general text>` as argument, as far as I know.

The situation is indeed completely different with `\if\lowercase\fi`, where `\lowercase` is *not* expandable, so TeX inserts `\relax` and the comparison can be performed (and is true).

Answer (score 18):

Not extremly short, but a real bug I ran into once when working on `xor`

```
\output{\deadcycles=1
        \message{.}%            just to show that something is happening
        \setbox0\box255}
\null
\bye
```

Of course the output routine didn't set `\deadcycles` to 1. In reality it was two ORs being called in a row the first setting it to zero.

Just realized that I only answered the second part of the question. By now the first part has already been answered by @egreg.

Comment: I knew your loops would be `\output`-related :) And sorry, you are right, I should've mentionned I knew the answer.

Answer (score 5):

A shorter loop just using classic tex and no macro expansion is

```
\let\par\relax.\vskip
```

or

```
\let

\noindent

\vskip
```

Comment: A variant of that is `\everypar{\par}.`

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch yes but that's more explicitly recursive

Comment: Can you please explain this one? Why does the `\vskip` not complain about a missing number?

Comment: @Skillmon it's just the way it is. `\vskip` forces `\par` before scanning for the length, so here it loops before scanning starts.

Comment: ahh, now I get it, thanks!

Comment: @Skillmon you inspired me to add a clearer version....