# How is \unexpanded defined?

Tags: macros, tex-core

I was wondering how `\etoolbox`'s `\expandonce` does what it does.  So I looked up how it was defined and found

```
\unexpanded\expandafter{#1}
```

But no matter where I look, I cannot find a definition for `\unexpanded`.  I've tried

```
 texdef -t latex unexpanded -s
```

which returns the following:

```
Source code definition of 'unexpanded' could not be found.
\unexpanded is defined by (La)TeX.

\unexpanded:
\unexpanded
```

I've also tried looking in the `source2e` documentation, but there's nothing there about `\unexpanded`.

Could someone point me in the right direction of where to find the documentation?

Comment: I think the texbook goes over it, but I can't quite remember. You won't find it in `source2e`.

Comment: `\unexpanded` is an eTeX primitive, have a look at [the eTeX manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/etex)

Comment: @cgnieder That's the answer here: please post as such

Comment: @cgnieder How do I find the source code for `eTeX` stuff?  Or how would I used `texdef` to show the source code?

Comment: @A.Ellett Trying to use `texdef` for `\unexpanded` is the same as trying to use it for say `\def` or `\relax`: you won't get anything. As it's a primitive, the source is in WEB (a form of Pascal), but unless you really need the detail then I'd go with the engine manual (eTeX in this case).

Comment: For cross-linking: special case of [macros - Where do I find out how a command/environment is defined? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4327/where-do-i-find-out-how-a-command-environment-is-defined/).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`\unexpanded` is an ε-TeX primitive. If you do

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\show\unexpanded
\end{document}
```

you'll get in the log:

```
> \unexpanded=\unexpanded.
l.3 \show\unexpanded
```

which seems to be redundant information but actually tells you that it is a primitive control sequence. Primitives are listed in the TeX Book or [TeX by Topic](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/texbytopic) but you won't find `\unexpanded` there because it is an ε-TeX primitive. It is described [in the e-TeX manual](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etex), though:

> `\unexpanded<general text>`.
>
> The expansion is the token list `<balanced text>`.
>
> [...]
>
> When building an expanded token list, the tokens resulting from the
>   expansion of `\unexpanded` are not expanded further (this is the same
>   behaviour as is exhibited by the tokens resulting from the expansion of
>   `\the<token>` variable in both TeX and ε-TeX).

Answer (score 26):

As cgnieder's excellent answer says, `\unexpanded` is a primitive of e-TeX, that is, an extension of the original TeX language. Primitives don't have a definition, they're commands directly understood by the engine. Some of them are expandable, that is, they don't reach TeX's “stomach” because they are expanded just like macros (the same happens to the conditionals, for example); `\unexpanded` is one of these macros.

It's a generalization of `\noexpand` which, in the context of an `\edef` or a `\write`, has a null expansion but also the effect of making the next token unexpandable for the task at hand. Thus

```
\def\foo{something}
\def\baz{else}
\edef\x{\foo\noexpand\baz}
```

would be equivalent to

```
\def\x{something\baz}
```

With `\unexpanded` you can protect from expansion in an `\edef` (or `\xdef`) or `\write` an entire token list, without the need to prepend `\noexpand` to all expandable tokens.

Since `\unexpanded` follows the pattern

```
\unexpanded <general text>
```

it has an interesting feature. When TeX wants to expand it, it looks forward to find a `<general text>` which is defined as

```
<filler> { <balanced text> <right brace>
```

and *expands* tokens to recognize a `<filler>` and, eventually, the `{`. A `<filler>` is just an arbitrary sequence of `\relax` and space tokens which are simply ignored. The `{` is an explicit or implicit token of category code 1.

A consequence of this is that

```
\unexpanded\expandafter{\cs}
```

will cause the expansion of `\cs` before the `{` that starts the list of tokens which will *not* be expanded any more. Indeed, the definition of `\expandonce` is

```
\newcommand{\expandonce}[1]{\unexpanded\expandafter{#1}}
```

Also `\detokenize` (another expandable primitive of e-TeX) has the same properties.

Beware of the `<filler>`: it can cause some unexpected effects under certain circumstances as shown in [Get the lion to run in loops. Tersely](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44452/get-the-lion-to-run-in-loops-tersely)

Comment: In an expansion context, things like `\def`, `\expandafter`, `\noexpand` are treated as though their expansion was `\relax`, right?  So, in the context of `\unexpanded`, when expanding the `<filler>`, TeX finds `\expandafter`, expands it and sees what amounts to `\relax`.  Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: @A.Ellett Sorry, you're not understanding this correctly. In an expansion context, unexpandable tokens are simply not expanded (they can't be); `\expandafter` and `\noexpand` *are* expandable and they *are* expanded. The expansion of both is null, but before this null expansion, they do their respective action.

Comment: What's the role of `<filler>` here? Does `\unexpanded` reads and executes the filler until it reaches a `{`? What if there is a `{` in the filler?

Comment: @Cyker The `<filler>` is any sequence of tokens that, after macro expansion, only consists of `\relax` or space tokens. Any other token ends it and, if it is not `{`, an error is issued.