# comment.sty and UTF8 encoding

Tags: unicode, comments

I noted that if I use comment.sty and a there is a block of text containing UTF8 characters inside a comment environment, the compilation aborts!

**Minimal Example**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}%this file is stored as UTF8 file!
\RequirePackage{comment}
\specialcomment{privateSolution}
    {\begingroup\itshape\noindent\textbf{Solution}\\}
    {\endgroup}
%\excludecomment{privateSolution}%Use it to remove solutions!

\begin{document}
\title{Comment.sty and UTF8 test file}
\maketitle
\section{UTF8 character test}
In which alphabet characters àìùòè are common?
\begin{privateSolution}
    The Italian alphabet contains àìùòè.
\end{privateSolution}

\begin{comment}
    The Italian one! It contains àìùòè.
\end{comment}
\end{document}
```

Has anyone the same problem?
Any workaround?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ciao! Avresti potuto semplicemente bussare sul muro!

Comment: No problems here (TeX Live2013). Perhaps an outdated package(s)?

Comment: I don't believe it is a problem of outdated package because I regularly update packages using TeX Live Utility in my Apple Mac (I currently use TeX Live 2013).
Are you sure to use UTF8 enconding when you save the example file?

Comment: Then I am missing something. I don't seem to see any problems in the final output and the compilation flows with no errors.

Comment: RobertoPose you could teach @egreg the mechanics of asking a question on this site, he hasn't managed it yet.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ask Roberto to also teach _you_, you don't seem to have read the manual either for that ;-)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem is in how `comments.sty` writes out files; when you input `à`, it *is* interpreted during a `\write` and it becomes the character corresponding to `à` in the T1 encoding.

Solution: modify `\ThisComment` to write out uninterpreted commands.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%this file is stored as UTF8 file!
\usepackage{comment}

\renewcommand\ThisComment[1]{%
  \immediate\write\CommentStream{\unexpanded{#1}}%
}

\specialcomment{privateSolution}
    {\itshape\noindent\textbf{Solution}\\}
    {}
%\excludecomment{privateSolution}%Use it to remove solutions!

\begin{document}
\title{Comment.sty and UTF8 test file}
\maketitle
\section{UTF8 character test}
In which alphabet characters àìùòè are common?
\begin{privateSolution}
    The Italian alphabet contains àìùòè.
\end{privateSolution}

\begin{comment}
    The Italian one! It contains àìùòè.
\end{comment}
\end{document}
```

A completely different solution using `environ`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%this file is stored as UTF8 file!
\usepackage{environ}

\newif\ifsolution
\NewEnviron{privateSolution}{%
  \ifsolution
    \par\noindent\textbf{\textit{Solution}}\\
    \BODY
  \fi
}
%\solutiontrue % Uncomment it to print solutions!

\begin{document}
\title{Comment.sty and UTF8 test file}
\maketitle
\section{UTF8 character test}
In which alphabet characters àìùòè are common?
\begin{privateSolution}
    The Italian alphabet contains àìùòè.
\end{privateSolution}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The @egreg's second solution is surely very elegant but it works only when the body of environment does not contain verbatim text/environments as, for example, [listings](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex2e/contrib/listings/).

Comment: @RobertoPose Indeed, that's a limitation of `environ`: environments defined with `\NewEnviron` absorb the content of the environment as a macro argument, so verbatim material cannot be used in them.

Comment: The `unexpanded' command is part of e-TeX
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140785/how-is-unexpanded-defined
so I can't very well use it as standard. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout LaTeX has been using e-TeX for several years.

Comment: Every single distribution? Anyway, testing for the presence of eTeX is easy enough, and an updated comment.sty is now on CTAN.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout e-TeX has been the default LaTeX engine for several years. Of course, several users may still be running on old distributions, but then they'll probably don't need UTF-8 support.

Answer (score 2):

With my apologies for tardiness -- I just don't do much TeX anymore lately -- version 3.8 of comment.sty has been uploaded and approved on CTAN. That should fix this problem. Much thanks to @egreg for the solution.