# Unrecognized special character with comment package

Tags: babel, unicode, input-encodings, font-encodings, comments

Why are the character with accent not recognized ?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{comment}

\includecomment{withsolution}

\begin{document}
\begin{withsolution}
à
\end{withsolution}
\end{document}
```

returned error:

```
! Paragraph ended before \UTFviii@three@octets was complete.
```

If I put it outside the comment environment, it works.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: ä,ö,etc. aren't recognized neither ;-)

Comment: Interesting. It happens only if the first character of the first line of the `withsolution` environment is an accented letter. Just putting a `\relax` (or even a simple space, which is ignored anyway) in front of it makes it work; no idea as why, though...

Comment: comment.sty doesn't work correctly with utf8. For a solution see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/159824/2388

Comment: It's 2015 and we have _two_ TeX engines that can handle Unicode natively. Why do you insist on using an 8-bit engine instead?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.