# How to enable unicode within comment section? (package "comment")

Tags: unicode, input-encodings, comments

In following MWE, letters with an accent that are within the personalized `comment` environment are generating following errors while compiling with `pdflatex`:

> ! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char �tr (U+F0)
>   (inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX.

**Question:** How to enable unicode characters within a `comment`-environment?

---

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{comment}
            \includecomment{mycomment}   

\begin{document}

    \section*{Normal text}
            Tous les êtres humains naissent libres et égaux en dignité et en droits.

    \section*{Text within a displayed personnalized comment}
\begin{mycomment}
        Tous les êtres humains naissent libres et égaux en dignité et en droits.
\end{mycomment}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Comment: **it is!** Thank you for noticing. I'm going to post an answer to mark it as resolved, but please let me know if the etiquette prefers to delete the duplicate question.

Comment: You can vote to close it or delete it. It's up to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(As noticed by **egreg**, this question is a duplicate of [comment.sty and UTF8 encoding](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159820/comment-sty-and-utf8-encoding))

The solution is to partially redefine the internal functioning of the `comment`.

The three lines added before `\begin{document}` in following MWE do the job!

---

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

        \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
        \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
        \usepackage{comment}
                \includecomment{mycomment} 

        \renewcommand\ThisComment[1]{%
                \immediate\write\CommentStream{\unexpanded{#1}}%
        }  

\begin{document}

        \section*{Normal text}
                Tous les êtres humains naissent libres et égaux en dignité et en droits.

        \section*{Text within a displayed personnalized comment}
\begin{mycomment}
            Tous les êtres humains naissent libres et égaux en dignité et en droits.
\end{mycomment}
\end{document}
```