# Defining a null environment

Tags: environments, amsmath

I am writing a mathematical document and I want to make a overview document, in which I only present the theorems and definitions and not the proofs, so I thought that I can change the environment *proof* to a null environment, which basically ignores the proofs or replaces them with one single space, or anything similar. I thought using the *comment* package and tried `\renewenvironment{proof}{\begin{comment} }{ \end{comment}}` but as it turns out `LaTeX` interprets `}{` as comment.

How can I achieve this neatly or is there a way to turn the proof off by `amsmath`?

Comment: You need to use `\in­clude­com­ment{proof}`...

Comment: When I do that I get inputenc error. I use German characters like ü and ß in the proofs.

Comment: @Werner -- this sounded like such a good idea.  but with `amsthm`, all that is omitted are the proof headers and qed marker; the text remains.  (i will write to the author.)

Comment: @gonenc -- `amsmath` shouldn't figure into this.  it's `amsthm` that formats theorems, and i've just determined that this doesn't work (at least not if i've used the same `comment` package that you did).

Comment: You might also look at the envrion package, which would use \RenewEnviron{proof}{\begin{comment}\BODY\end{comment}}

Comment: Related/duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159820/comment-sty-and-utf8-encoding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this is a solution: `\gobble` the content away with a `\RenewEnviron{proof}{}{}` that has no `\BODY` command, i.e. the `\BODY` is 'thrown away'.

I used the first `proof` environment to show some content and then redefined `proof`, the second content isn't display any longer then.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{environ}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
Brontosaurs were large
\end{proof}


\RenewEnviron{proof}{%
% How not to be seen?
}{}

\begin{proof}
Brontosaurs were large
\end{proof}



\end{document}
```

[image]