# \nolimits by default in every display-mode equation

Tags: math-mode

I would like to use `\nolimits` on every operator like `\sum`, `\min`, `\max`, etc. in display-mode equations, as it allows me to save a lot of space. How can I achieve this without having to manually write it everywhere?

Comment: Doing a flight of stairs is more tiring than asking here. `;-)` See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159820/comment-sty-and-utf8-encoding#comment365136_159820

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `amsmath`, then just load it as

```
\usepackage[nosumlimits,nonamelimits]{amsmath}
```

Complete example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nosumlimits,nonamelimits]{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\sum_{k=1}^n k\ne\max_{1\le k\le n}\{k\}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]