# Split a long equation across lines with the numbering bottom aligned

Tags: amsmath, superscripts, equation-number

I try to write this equation on overleaf and numbering in second line (the same as in the picture) but I couldn't. Another problem is when I use align or equation, the prime in max' function goes to the center but not the right of max. Help me!!

[image]

Comment: Welcome. No need to shout in the header.  Without code we can't hardly help you. This is certainly possible with the `align` or the `alignat` environment with `\nonumber` on the first line. For the `\max` problem, use `\nolimits` or a [package option](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/369960).

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `align`.

See the code below on how to get max'.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\pmax}{max^{\prime}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
(-\partial_uJ(\bar{y},\bar{u}),h)_{L^2} = (p,h)_{L^2}
&= (-\Delta\delta+\pmax(\bar{y};\delta),p)_{L^2} \notag \\
&= (-\Delta\delta+\chi\delta,p)_{L^2}+(\pmax(\bar{y};\delta)-\chi\delta,p)_{L^2}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much!!! you saved my life!!!