# \noexpand, \unexpanded and \expandafter

Tags: macros, expansion

Recently I discovered a piece of code (from `ucharclasses`) using three expansion-related macros `\noexpand`, `\unexpanded` and `\expandafter`:

```
\def\do#1{\noexpand\setTransitionsFor{#1}{####1}{####2}}
\def\doclass#1{
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand\newcommand
    \unexpanded\expandafter{\csname setTransitionsFor#1\endcsname}[2]%
    {\csname #1Classes\endcsname}}\x}
\ClassGroups
```

I can find some references about these macros, but I still don't understand what they are doing exactly. I'd like to know why they are necessary in the above piece of code, and why would we ever need four sharps as in `####1` and `####2`.

Comment: Here's an excellent tutorial on `\expandafter`: [TUGBoat 9(1):57-61, 1988](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb09-1/tb20bechtolsheim.pdf).

Comment: @John OK. So `\expandafter` knows about `\csname` and `\endcsname`. That's a case explicitly listed. But in this piece of code there's `unexpanded` before `\expandafter` that still looks confusing.

Comment: David Carlisle has given a great answer, below.  To reply to your comment, the role of `\unexpanded` is discussed in [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140785/how-is-unexpanded-defined).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\do` shows `\noexpand` and `##`

```
\def\do#1{\noexpand\setTransitionsFor{#1}{####1}{####2}}

\edef\z{\do{abc}}
\show\z
```

this shows

```
> \z=macro:
->\setTransitionsFor {abc}{##1}{##2}.
l.4 \show\z
```

So you see that in defining `\z` with `\edef` the csname `\setTransitionsFor` was prevented from being expanded by the `\noexpand` , `#1` got replaced by the argument to `\do` which is `abc` here and `##` got replaced by `#`

For the second macro, adding `\show\x` then running this fragment with pdflatex

```
\def\doclass#1{
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand\newcommand
    \unexpanded\expandafter{\csname setTransitionsFor#1\endcsname}[2]%
    {\csname #1Classes\endcsname}}%
    \show\x
    \x}

\doclass{abc}
```

produces

```
> \x=macro:
->\endgroup \newcommand \setTransitionsForabc [2]{\abcClasses }.
\doclass ...csname #1Classes\endcsname }}\show \x 
                                                  \x 
l.9 \doclass{abc}
                 
? x
```

so after the `\show` the temporary macro `\x` will be executed and be equivalent to

```
\newcommand \setTransitionsForabc [2]{\abcClasses }
```

so the string `abc` that was passed to `\doclass` has been used to construct both the commandnames `\setTransitionsForabc`  and `\abcClasses`

Comment: Can we say `\noexpand` protects the next *one* token, while `\unexpanded` protects the entire token list between `{` and `}`?

Comment: @Cyker yes,  exactly.noexpand is classic Tex , unexpanded is an etex addition.

Comment: And there seems to be another trick in this code: The use of `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` is meant to hide the definition of `\x` so that it doesn't pollute the current scope?

Comment: @Cyker you are getting the hang of this:) yes