# Why is \unexpanded not respected after an \if?

Tags: tex-core, conditionals, expansion

I was surprised to find that the argument of an `\unexpanded` is expanded if the `\unexpanded` is within the first two tokens after an `\if`.
Using Knuth TeX's `\noexpand` instead works but I am curious where the difference is.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

    \def\endtoken{~}
    
    \typeout{! ========== tracing 1 ==========}
    \tracingmacros=2
    \tracingcommands=3
    
%   \if \expandafter\noexpand\endtoken \noexpand~% this would work
    \if \unexpanded\expandafter{\endtoken} \noexpand~% this does not
        true
    \else
        false
    \fi
    
    \tracingcommands=0
    \tracingmacros=0
    \typeout{! ========== tracing 0 ==========}

\end{document}
```

The `\expandafter` which expands the argument of the `\unexpanded` once makes no difference.
`~` is expanded all the way with or without it and the result is the same.

`\tracingmacros` shows how `~` is expanded and `\tracingcommands` shows that `\if` evaluates to true.
I am assuming that it comes to this result by comparing `\protect` and `\unhbox` which are both inserted by expanding `~` and are equal because they are both control sequences.
Is there a tracing command which would show which tokens TeX compares when evaluating a conditional?
(I have scanned through the [great list of tracing commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60494) but have not found this among it unfortuantely.)

(The exclamation mark at the beginning of the `\typeout` makes TeXstudio think there was an error so that it provides me with a link to the position in the log file where the output of the tracing commands begins and ends. This may, however, have the unintended side effect that it does not load the pdf although it has been built correctly.)

Why is the argument of `\unexpanded` expanded after an `\if` (not inside of an `\edef`) but a token following a `\noexpand` is not expanded, even after an `\if`?

The interesting question [Get the lion to run in loops. Tersely.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44452/120953) also deals with `\if` and `\unexpanded` but I think it does not answer this question because there the `\fi` is in the `<filler>` of `\unexpanded` but here after the `<balanced text>` and the closing curly brace.

Comment: I think the difference between `\noexpand` and `\unexpanded` is worth detailing, but @egreg is right that the test here is ... not really correct

Comment: Side note, basically, if I understood correctly `\edef` etc. "hard code" `\the\toks` etc. to insert the content verbatim, so • first, # are not halved • even if you do `\edef\something{\expandafter\empty\unexpanded{...}}`, `\unexpanded` loses its magic even if it's inside an edef.

Comment: @user202729 to explain in more detail what's going on in your example: First the `\edef` expands the `\expandafter` which expands the `\unexpanded`. During this expansion `\unexpanded` does it's magic but that has no effect because `\expandafter` expands only a single token. Then `\edef` continues to expand the remaining tokens, first the `\empty` and then the `...` which is now unprotected because the `\unexpanded` has been removed by the `\expandafter`. (The curly braces have been removed when expanding the `\unexpanded`.)

Comment: No, it's not "`\expandafter` expands only a single token", it's that "`\unexpanded` (like `\the\toks`) only protects the content inside when it's in a `\edef`". If you do `\expandafter\empty\romannumeral ...`, arbitrarily many tokens after `\romannumeral` will be expanded until a complete number is formed.

Comment: true, `\def\bar{2} \romannumeral1\unexpanded{\bar}` expands `\bar` and so does `\expandafter\show\csname foo\unexpanded{\bar}\endcsname`. Thanks for pointing that out. Guess I still haven't really gotten used to `\unexpanded`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `\unexpanded` primitive is essentially an anonymous toks, which means no expansion within an `\edef` or similar, whereas `\noexpand` explicitly changes the behaviour of the next token to be equal to `\relax` for one expansion. This is perhaps easier to see if we choose to typeset the results of the two:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\demo}{FOO}
Text \noexpand\demo\space text \unexpanded{\demo} text.
\end{document}
```

The first `\demo` is turned into `\relax` for this reading, and so does nothing. In contrast, the second is effectively passed through `\toks0{\demo}\the\toks0`, and so typesets normally.

---

As [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) points out, one can also see the effect in

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\expandafter\edef\expandafter\foo\expandafter{\unexpanded{~}} 
\show\foo
\expandafter\edef\expandafter\foo\expandafter{\noexpand~}
\show\foo
\end{document}
```

Comment: In `expl3` code this is important where we return tokens protected from expansion: we always use `\unexpanded` in case we are not inside an `e`/`x`-type context.

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that `\unexpanded` behaves as if it would save the balanced text in a toks register (as described in [TeX by Topic](https://ctan.org/pkg/texbytopic) Chapter 14: *Token Lists*) and then inserts it like with a `\the` (except that this does not influence any of the registers that you can access with `\the`)? So the balanced text is *not* expanded if `\unexpanded` is expanded by `\edef` (or `\xdef`) but expanded anywhere else?

Comment: @jakun Exactly: the code _is_ that for a toks, just without the need to assign to a real one