# Is it possible to \noexpand a TeX group instead of a macro?

Tags: macros, expansion

I often find myself in need of a `\noexpand` utility that works on a TeX group rather than a macro. For example, in my current project, I have subroutines:

```
% adds a box to the layer
\newcommand\addbox[1] {
   \edef\drawboxcode{
      {\noexpand\draw (...) node[
         draw,
         fill,
         ...] {#1};
      }
   }
   \expandafter\addcodetolayer\drawboxcode
}

% pushes object code onto layer
\newcommand\addcodetolayer[1]
    {\seq_gput_right:Nn\sq__layercmds{#1}}

% renders layer
\newcommand\renderlayer
    {\seq_use:Nnnn \sq__layercmds{}{}{}}
```

I require these because the code I use to draw TikZ objects is divided into subroutines that place content on multiple PGF layers (e.g. a box on one layer, a shadow on another layer) in an interleaved way and, unfortunately, every time the `\begin{pgfonlayer}{foolayer}` environment is used, it wipes out any content in the `foolayer` layer previously written.

My recourse has been to use the subroutines above in the following way:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \addbox {Foo Box}
   \addbox {Bar Box}
   ...
   \begin{pgfonlayer}{boxlayer}
      \renderlayer
   \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This works well but has one outstanding problem: the argument to `\addbox`, if it contains macros such as `\ref`, must have these manually `\noexpand`-ed to avoid errors, i.e.

```
\addbox {Foo Box (section~\ref{sec:foo})}  % gives horrible cryptic LaTeX errors
\addbox {Foo Box (section~\noexpand\ref{sec:foo})}  % works like a charm
```

Ideally I would like to avoid this, but I know of no good way to do it. The most obvious fix would be if `\noexpand` could work on TeX groups rather than macros, but it doesn't. Using

```
   \edef\drawboxcode{
      {\noexpand\draw (...) node[
         draw,
         fill,
         ...] {\noexpand{#1}};
      }
   }
```

does nothing, for instance. I also can't use

```
   \def\drawboxcontent{#1}
   \edef\drawboxcode{
      {\noexpand\draw (...) node[
         draw,
         fill,
         ...] {\noexpand\drawboxcontent};
      }
   }
```

because when `\drawboxcontent` is finally expanded in `\renderlayer`, the macro will only contain the content of the last added box.

This is just one example of where a utility that prevents `\edef` from expanding a block of code (i.e. TeX group) rather than a macro would be extremely useful.

One alternative would be a utility that allowed code such as

```
   \passbyvaluedef\drawboxcontent{#1}
   \edef\drawboxcode{
      {\noexpand\draw (...) node[
         draw,
         fill,
         ...] {\drawboxcontent};
      }
   }
```

where `\passbyvaluedef` would define a macro `\drawboxcontent` that, when expanded, would expand into some unique command sequence `\drawboxcontentaaaa` *without expanding further*, and `\drawboxcontentaaaa` would contain whatever was in `#1`. The next time `\passbyvaluedef\drawboxcontent` was called, `\drawboxcontent` would expand into `\drawboxcontentaaab`, and so on, returning a unique CS name in each case. This is less elegant than a group-based `\noexpand`, but it would also get the job done.

Are there any TeX/LaTeX macros/packages for doing either of these things (effectively `\noexpand`-ing groups, or the suggested alternative)? If not, is there another way to solve the problem of having to manually include `\noexpand`s in my box contents, or am I stuck with them?

Comment: do you look for \unexpanded?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Never heard of it. I'll look it up. Thanks.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Sonuvagun. Works perfectly. Thanks. If you'd put it in an official answer, I'll happily give you the green check. :)

Comment: Side note, `unexpanded`'s behavior is like `\the\toks0` instead of like `\noexpand` each token, which is the same inside an `\edef` (which is the case here) but might be different in other cases e.g. [tex core - Why is \unexpanded not respected after an \if? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/497645/why-is-unexpanded-not-respected-after-an-if).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `\unexpanded{<balanced text>}`. This will avoid the expansion in the `<balanced text>`.