# Why can \if come between a base and the digits in a literal integer, but \relax can't?

Tags: tex-core

If I write

`\count10=\iftrue'\fi10 \the\count10`

then the answer is 8, because the "if" clause adds a `'` which causes `10` to be interpreted as octal.

If I write this, the answer is also 8:

```
\count10='\iftrue\fi10
\the\count10
```

However, if I switch out the "if" clause for a different expandable-- say, `\relax`:

```
\count10='\relax10
\the\count10
```

then it fails:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.16 \count10='\relax
                     10
```

What makes the difference?

Comment: well \relax stops the parsing for a number, you would get a similar error if you put `x` there.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer is that a special property of `\relax`, then, and I just happened to pick the expandable that didn't work like the if clause?

Comment: ??? `\relax` is *the* "most popular" nonexpandable command though? (in the sense that its only purpose to exist is to be unexpandable) If you try `\empty` it would work.

Comment: Well, now I feel a bit of a numpty!

Comment: @MarnanelThurman ... if you want to get more confused, take at look at my 2006 (sic!)  TeX Pearl "\relax ex machina II"  ( https://www.gust.org.pl/projects/pearls/2006p/bernd-raichle/bachotex2006-bernd-raichle-pearl1.pdf ): you can browse through TeX.web, the source code of TeX, to find these unusual places at which TeX will ignore = read over a \relax token.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are contexts where `\relax` is ignored during the scan for the argument to a primitive command, but this is not one of them.

The TeXbook defines a ⟨filler⟩ as any sequence of space and `\relax` tokens; when it is scanning for `{`, a ⟨filler⟩ is ignored. Note, however that the TeXbook uses `{` to denote an explicit or implicit character token of category code 1. So a ⟨filler⟩ is ignored when looking for the argument in a token register assignment or in a `\lowercase` operation (see [Get the lion to run in loops. Tersely](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44459/4427) for a peculiar aspect).

Another case when `\relax` is ignored is when it is used for ending an expression to be passed to `\numexpr`, `\dimexpr`, `\glueexpr` or `\muexpr`.

When TeX wants to determine the argument for an assignment to a `\count` register, it looks for an optional `=` and then expands tokens (if expandable, of course) as long as it finds something that can be interpreted as an integer (which may include a prefix for the radix). At the first token that cannot be interpreted as valid input for a number in the chosen radix, the search stops and the number is evaluated for storing.

<sub>Important exception: when TeX has determined that an integer is in alphabetic format, that is, when the prefix is `` ` `` (backquote), it stops expanding tokens and takes the next character token or length one control sequence to be the alphabetic constant, translating it into ASCII code (or Unicode, for Unicode engines). An error would be raised if the input is incorrect.</sub>

Let's examine your attempts

```
\count10=\iftrue'\fi10 \the\count10
\count10='\iftrue\fi10 \the\count10
\count10='\relax10
```

In the first case TeX finds something expandable after `=` and expands it. Well, the expansion of `\iftrue` is empty and then `'` is scanned because it's part or the “true text”; now TeX knows that it wants to look for an octal constant. Next it finds `\fi`, whose expansion is empty and next `1`, then `0` and finally a space that ends the scanning process. The number is computed and the value stored in the register; the space is ignored and processing continues, in this case printing the value stored in the register.

The second case is completely similar. But the third one has a problem: after `'` there's `\relax` that's ***not*** ignored. It is an unexpandable token that cannot be interpreted as an octal digit and TeX stops with an error, because just the radix prefix is not a valid number.

Out of curiosity, here's another case that fails:

```
\chardef\foo=10
\count10='\foo
```

A `\chardef` token *can* be used in the context of a number, but not with a radix prefix: it is an “abstract” number, just like in

```
\count10=\count255
```

The prefixes `'` and `"` can only be used in front of an explicit number, that is, a sequence of digits in the appropriate range.

Comment: Thank you! That was a very comprehensive and helpful answer.

Comment: In the case of `\numexpr` saying "ignore" may not be the most accurate description, as it gobbles exactly one `\relax` -- if there are two `\relax` they won't be "ignored" the same way.

Comment: @user202729 Did I say that you can use any number of `\relax` tokens?